# Apache Zeppelin on EMR login error

Tags: amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I have setup an EMR 4.4 cluster with Zeppelin/Spark configured. I successfully managed to setup Zeppelin on localhost and was logged in as anonymous. I added created a user and password and continued to work with my notebook. I later started a new cluster and I am now presented with a login screen for Zeppelin which will not accept my username and password. Is there a way to flush the privileges or find out what I did enter?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the port at the end and it allowed access.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8890/
```